# "Tomorrow’s lesson is to introduce the present simple tense to your students."

Tags: sentence-meaning

My question is, in the following sentence, what would you guys phrase it as?

> Tomorrow’s lesson is to introduce the present simple tense to your students.

What is this sentence an example of?.... a grammar point of the lesson or is it the objective of the lesson or do you think it is a combination of both?

1. A grammar point of the lesson
2. The objective of the lesson

or both of the above?

I would think that it references both the grammar point as well as the objective , but I would really appreciate any feedback as well as your reasoning behind your choice?

Comment: To teach a grammar point is the objective of the lesson. So I honestly don't see any difference in meaning between your 1. and 2., in context

Answer (score 1):

The objective is 'introduce'. The target is a grammatical structure.

According to the quoted sentence, the stated objective is "to introduce" something. Within 'introduce' there could be a variety of activities that get the students familiar with whatever the topic is. It assumes that whatever is to be done in the lesson is new to the learners.

The thing that is being introduced is an aspect of language - grammar. In this case, the grammar to be focused on is the Present simple tense.

Comment: Good answer. I was going to +1, but my only reservation was I wasn't quite clear on what OP is asking. "What is this sentence an example of?" is vague and unclear. Is the question asking about the meaning of the quoted sentence? If it weren't for your answer I'd have closed the question.